# shared preferences First Time Empty When i restart the app with out logout Code works Fine

Tags: android

Problem is i have stored Facebook username email id and profile picture and retrieving data in next activity but the problem is when i log in the data is null when i restart the App code working fine.

### Storing Data

```
String email = object.getString("email");

String id = object.getString("id");`
sessionManager.setfacebookid(object.getString("email").toString());


String imageurl = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + id + "/picture?type=large";

sessionManager.setfacebookimage("https://graph.facebook.com/" + id + "/picture?type=large".toString());
```

### Retrieving Data

sessionManager.isUserLogin();
            navHeader = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);

```
        String facebookname = sessionManager.getfacebookname();
        tvvwelcome2 = (TextView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.tvwelcome2);
        tvvwelcome2.setText(facebookname);
        Log.e("facebooknamein text....", "" + facebookname);

        String facebookid = sessionManager.getfacebookid();

        tvemail2 = (TextView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.headeremail2);

        tvemail2.setText(facebookid);

        Log.e("emailfbinnavigation", "" + facebookid);

        String facedp = sessionManager.getfacebookdp();

        imgbtn2 = (ImageView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.profileheader2);

        Picasso.with(this).load(facedp).into(imgbtn2);

        Log.e("imageview in image", "" + facedp);
```

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Post your **SessionManager** class where you missed out something.

Answer (score 0):

Try using SharedPreferences like below mentioned,

To save data:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("my_prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("name", "Sahil");
editor.commit();
```

To retrieve data:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("my_prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
String name= prefs.getString("name");
```

Comment: if there is no such value for the parameter you are using to store value then it will show null for the first time, after that it will show data. Otherwise can you please share your sharedpreference code.

Comment: public void setfacebookid(String fbid){
        editor.putString(KEY_FAcebook_id,fbid);
        editor.commit();

    }
    public String getfacebookid(){
        return pref.getString(KEY_FAcebook_id,"");
    }

Comment: Please confirm that you are using same sharedpreference.

Comment: yes,anyway thanks for answer ....i think i have to retrieve data in onResume instead of on create